# Matplotlib 3D-Surface of "bumpy-function" does not work

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to Plot the 3D Curve to this function:

[image: func]

it should look something like this
[image: bumpy]

I did following in Python 3.x (I wanted to analyse this in sympy so i created a symbolic version of the function, too):

```
from sympy import init_printing
init_printing()
import sympy as sp

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d import Axes3D

x1, x2=sp.symbols('x1 x2')
F=np.abs(((sp.cos(x1))**4+(sp.cos(x2))**4-2*((sp.cos(x1))**2)*  ((sp.cos(x2))**2))/(sp.sqrt(x1**2+2*x2**2)))

F_lam=sp.lambdify((x1,x2),F,modules='numpy')
x1_t=np.linspace(0.5,10,num=100)
x2_t=np.linspace(0.5,10,num=100)

X1,X2=np.meshgrid(x1_t,x2_t)
Z=F_lam(x1_t,x2_t)


fig = plt.figure(figsize=(14,6))

ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 2, 1, projection='3d')
p = ax.plot_surface(X1, X2, Z, linewidth=0)
```

But i get this:

[image: bad_bumpy]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You called your function for the wrong arrays:

```
Z=F_lam(X1, X2)
```

But it would be better if matplotlib would give an error, that the shapes are not right.

Comment: Note: I would also set rstride to 1.